# Receiving files over socket

Tags: java, xml, sockets, io

I am implementing a [Direct Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_%28file_sharing%29) client. I am using the [NMDC protocol](http://nmdc.sourceforge.net/NMDC.html). I can connect to a hub and other connected clients. I am trying to retrieve the file list from each client, I understand that in order to do that one must download the file `files.xml.bz2` from the other client. The protocol to download a file is as follows:

```
  ->   $ADCGET file <filename> <params>|
  <-   $ADCSND file <fileName> <params>|
  <-   (*** binary data is now transfered from client B to client A ***)
```

I am trying to create a file named `files.xml.bz2` using the binary data received. Here's my code:

```
//filesize is provided through the $ADCSND response from other client
byte[] data = new byte[filesize];
/*

Reading binary data from socket inputstream

*/
int read = 0;                       
for (int i=0; read<filesize;){
    int available = in2.available();
    int leftspace = filesize-read;
    if (available>0){
        in2.read(data, read, available>leftspace? leftspace:available);
        ++i;
    }
    read += (available>leftspace? leftspace:available)+1;
}
/*
writing the bytes to an actual file
*/
ByteArrayInputStream f = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("files.xml.bz2");
file.write(data);
file.close();
```

The file is created, however, the contents (files.xml) are not readable. Opening it in firefox gives:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
```

Viewing the contents in the terminal only reads binary data. What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I also tried Decompressing the file using the bz2 libray from Apache Ant.

```
ByteArrayInputStream f = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
BZip2CompressorInputStream bzstream = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(f);
FileOutputStream xmlFile = new FileOutputStream("files.xml");
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while((bzstream.read(bytes))!=-1){
    xmlFile.write(bytes);
}
xmlFile.close();
bzstream.close();
```

I get an error, here's the stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream is not in the BZip2 format
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream.init(BZip2CompressorInputStream.java:240)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream.<init>(BZip2CompressorInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream.<init>(BZip2CompressorInputStream.java:109)
    at control.Controller$1.run(Controller.java:196)
```

Comment: Well, given the file name, it looks like it is compressed with bzip2. Have you tried and decompressed it and see whether the contents match what you want?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't help. Also, are you saying it is impossible to simply receive and save the bz2 file without decompressing it?

Comment: (how didn't it help?) I didn't say that. You can save the file compressed without any problem. Therefore it appears that you don't save what you think you save... More code is needed (how do you deal with the command etc)

Comment: how did you got the filesize at the receiving end?

Comment: as highlighted in the comments in the code, the $ADCSND response from the other client includes the filesize. An example of a response would be `$ADCSND file files.xml.bz2 0 29725 ZL1`, the `29715` is the size in bytes.

Comment: @fge The full src can be found at http://goo.gl/ZtLA0f , beginning at line 170

Comment: You have a problem with your read loop starting line 182 (and which is in the extract above): you don't grab the number of bytes which were actually written. You should `int count; while ((count = bzstream.read(bytes)) != -1) xmlFile.write(bytes, 0, count);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `java.io.IOException: Stream is not in the BZip2 format` is generated by the constructor of class `BZip2CompressorInputStream`. I decided to scan the bytes, looking for the `magic number` to make sure that the file was bz2 format, it turns out that Java was right -- it wasnt in bz2 format.

Upon examining the source code of [Jucy](http://jucy.eu/), I saw that the reason for this was a slight error in the command I sent to the other client, in essence, this error was caused a mistake in my protocol implementation. The solution was:

Replace:

```
$ADCGET file files.xml.bz2 0 -1 ZL1|
```

With:

```
$ADCGET file files.xml.bz2 0 -1|
```

`ZL1` specifies compression of the files being sent (Not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Usual, typical misuse of `available().` All you need to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
{
     out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this with any size buffer greater than zero, but preferably several kilobytes. You don't need a new buffer per iteration, and you don't need to know how much data is available to read without blocking, as you have to block, otherwise you're just smoking the CPU.  But you do need to know how much data was actually read per iteration, and this is the first place where your code falls down.

Comment: Thanx you and @fge for your answers, however, the error `Stream is not in the BZip2 format` is generated by the constructor of `BZip2CompressorInputStream` therefore it does not even reach the while loop you guys are referring to. I fixed my error though.